# Unable to connect more than one USB 3.0 Basler Cameras

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect 2 Basler Cameras by setting respective device ids using [pylon_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/pylon_camera) node. But it does not pick the device id correctly. Without setting the device id it works.

I have set the permission for USB devices as mention here (https://www.baslerweb.com/fp-1510124600/media/downloads/documents/readme/README.txt) by executing ./setup-usb.sh . But when I specify the device id (e.g, 2676:ba02:2:2:8) in the config file it does not detect the corresponding device. This is the error it is throwing

```
[ INFO] [1531469242.730556970]: Trying to open the following camera: 2676:ba02:2:2:8
 [ERROR] [1531469242.994999730]: Couldn't find the camera that matches the given DeviceUserID: 2676:ba02:2:2:8! Either the ID is wrong or the cam is not yet connected
```

Maybe device id was set incorrectly. Anybody who can comment on this much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297261/unable-to-connect-more-than-one-usb-3.0-basler-cameras/) by [GPrathap](https://answers.ros.org/users/31593/gprathap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After spending lots of time, finally found the proper way to get this resolved. Here is the step you need to follow,

Once  [pylon_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/pylon_camera) is installed, there is a lib called pylon_camera_write_device_user_id_to_camera which can be found in the 
/ros/lib/pylon_camera/ directory. Just plug one camera at a time and assign a device id to the selected camera as follow,

```
ros/lib/pylon_camera/pylon_camera_write_device_user_id_to_camera traffic_left<this is the id of the camera>
```

Then in the config file, define the device which was assigned.

---

Originally posted by [GPrathap](https://answers.ros.org/users/31593/gprathap/) with karma: 36 on 2018-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JimTal](https://answers.ros.org/users/38959/jimtal/) on 2018-12-11**:
I am also working with multiple Basler USB 3.0 cameras in ROS and wanted to ask a couple of question.

1. Once the user id is assigned to the camera is it persistent and does not need to be rewritten on each camera power up?
2. How does one synchronize the camera (2 or more)?
3. Stereo imaging tips?

**Comment by [GPrathap](https://answers.ros.org/users/31593/gprathap/) on 2018-12-12**:\

1. Once the user id is assigned to the camera is it persistent and does not need to be rewritten on each camera power up? Nope,
2. 2. How does one synchronize the camera (2 or more)? 3. Stereo imaging tips? I dont get you where you want to synchronize? better to ask as a separate question